# How to exclude a child from the parent css property?

Tags: html, css

Im working on the opacity of an element using css. a paragraph is place in a div but when i set the opacity of the div to 0.4 the paragraph also affect. I tried to override the div in the paragraph by asigning the opacity 1.0 by this doesnt work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. That is just how opacity works.

A longer answer depends on what are you actually trying to achieve (the old XY Problem).

If, for instance, you wanted the background of the div to be translucent, but not the paragraph then you could solve that by using a translucent background instead of making the entire div translucent.

Comment: how about other properties such as color?Is there anyway I can select the parent element and exclude the child element. For instance, I only want the text in the div to be red but not in the paragraph which is the child of the div

Comment: If a property is inherited (which color is by default) then you can only write a selector that matches the paragraph and give it a different colour explicitly. There is no way to say "inherit from grandparent".

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know to fix this is to separate the background from the content:

```
<div id="container" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="background" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0.4; background: #ccc;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="content">Your content here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this earlier.
If I remember right, I set the `position:absolute;` to the innerDiv, hence the opacity property works well.

Another way to achieve this effect is to set the background of the outerDiv with alpha instead of opacity;
For eg:
change

```
.outerDiv{
  background-color: white; //or #fff or rgb(255,255,255) 
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

to

```
.outerDiv{
  background-color: rgba(225,225,225,0.4);
}
```

The fourth value is the alpha which works like opacity. It will not bother the contents of the div.